# Is there a tool that helps manage questions/answers that arise from Subversion commits?

Tags: svn, version-control

I work on a large, cross-team code base and quite often will notice code that looks like a possible bug/unnecessary bottleneck. Is there a tool (compatible with Win 7) that allows me to attach questions to files in Subversion repositories?

In a similar way to GUIs like TortoiseSVN, ideally this tool would change the file icon to indicate a pending enquiry, and save a history of Q&As for any given file, including older revisions.

Obviously, proper commit messages go some way to solving this problem, but with numerous contributors from different teams, this sometimes isn't realistic and also relies upon the person committing being aware of the pitfalls they may be adding.

I fully expect that a tool exactly like this doesn't exist, but any similar solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you want to integrate code reviews into your SVN workflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99707/whats-the-best-way-to-do-a-code-review-with-subversion-svn

Comment: @Oded:  Code reviews won't necessarily work across teams.  They're well worth having, of course.

Comment: @Oded: I was looking for something more impersonal and less likely to cause friction across teams who don't know each other well (or each other's cultures, even). I'm hoping a Q&A style tool would make the process more objective. However I've only ever done face-to-face code reviews, so perhaps I'm dismissing code-review tools too readily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add a custom subversion property.

Later on, you can write scripts that scan repositories for your custom subversion property.  It's not a perfect solution, but it affords you a lot of flexibility.  A system that imposes too much required behavior, or makes assumptions about the nature of the questions (like a code review system) might not always work out if your intended use doesn't match their functional offerings.

Answer (score 0):

One this we have that addresses this issue really well is SVN commit emails. Everyone in engineering get all SVN commit emails at our office. I set it up so that it can be filtered by SVN modules or by SVN repositories, that way teams can focus only on emails relevant to them. These emails contain the diffs from previous revisions (with clickable links that load the files in SVN web views in a browser). We use this for many many purposes, for tracking changes to a module, to code reviews to discussing further changes or refactoring.

We use [svnspam](http://code.google.com/p/svnspam/) for this and it has helped us out very well.

Note that currently it doesnt do binary file diffs and addition or deletion of files, but we use mailer.conf to handle it. This way we get ALL commits.